# Bash/Shell: Get the list of newest files by ctime in directory, sort and retrieve only 3 for each of them

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following files in a directory:

```
trunk_rev.94564.zip
trunk_rev.94565.zip
trunk_rev.94566.zip
trunk_rev.94567.zip
trunk_rev.94568.zip
trunk_rev.94569.zip
v15_rev.94560.zip
v15_rev.94561.zip
v15_rev.94562.zip
v15_rev.94563.zip
v15_rev.94564.zip
```

How could I get a list of N (e.g. 3) newest by ctime files for each pattern ? Filenames could be different.
E.g.:

```
trunk_rev.94567.zip
trunk_rev.94568.zip
trunk_rev.94569.zip
v15_rev.94562.zip
v15_rev.94563.zip
v15_rev.94564.zip
<some_another_file>.zip
<some_another_file>.zip
<some_another_file>.zip
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. What have you tried so far to accomplish your goal? Which problem did you face? My first thought is to do a little bash script... but beware that it is in general dangerous (and deprecated) to [parse the output of ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), mainly because the unforeseen presence of space or special characters (newline, tab...) in the filename.  Please [edit] your question with your attempt and problem.

Comment: Are you asking people here to do your homework or something?

Comment: @Radoo, nice sarcasm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
ls -1rt | awk 'BEGIN { FS="."; OFS="."; } { if (count[$1]<3) { count[$1]++; filenames[i++]=$0; } } END { for ( i in filenames ) { printf("%s\n",filenames[i]); } }'
```

The files will be listed by ctime order only.

To list them by ctime grouped by name, add a **sort** command:

```
ls -1rt | awk 'BEGIN { FS="."; OFS="."; } { if (count[$1]<3) { count[$1]++; filenames[i++]=$0; } } END { for ( i in filenames ) { printf("%s\n",filenames[i]); } }' | sort -t . -k 1,1
```

Comment: __Warning__: This will work only if in the filename are not present special character as the newline one. You can paste the newline for example renaming a pdf file from the title of the document written inside... So use it with wisdom. It can be harmful to [parse the output of ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) mainly because the presence of special characters in the filename. It's easy to do a fast script that works today and think tomorrow that it is solid and generally valid... Moreover what will happen if you have `v15_rev.bis.01`..`09` and `v15_rev.01`?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the manual of **ls** at this point:

> -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information) with -l: show ctime and sort by name 
>   other-wise: sort by ctime, newest first

and the manual of **head**, if you are not familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ls -l --time-style=full-iso | sort -k6 | tail -n3
```